# How can we change the date format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

Given the data `2018-04-28T18:38:23Z`

When I use `Date(2018-04-28T18:38:23Z)`

This gives me `Sat Apr 28 2018 18:38:23 GMT-0500`

I want to remove that GMT thing, but how can I do with simply without

writing some long code to parse it out?

Comment: You can style the date any way you wish. It will require some lines of code, but not many. See here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Comment: @ecg8—please don't reference w3schools, [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-objects) are much better resources.

Comment: @RobG, both those are great sites, but so is w3schools. I learned a lot of shit from them.

Comment: @ecg8—unfortunately it's full of errors, such as "*The getFullYear() method returns the year of a date as a four digit number*", which is simply wrong. The benefit of MDN is that being a public wiki, anyone can fix such errors as soon as they are found and a dedicated band of maintainers keeps it up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaScript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) has some methods you could use to craft the String you want.

Here's something close, you could play around with the methods (getHours/Minutes/Seconds), but if you want exactly that without the timezone, I would recommend parsing out or doing some String manipulation:

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toDateString() + " " + d.toLocaleTimeString());

// Output:   
// Sat Apr 28 2018 4:58:05 PM
```

Comment: This question shouldn't have been answered, there are many, many duplicates.